# Modal verbs with passive continuous

Tags: modal-verbs, passive-voice, present-continuous

> *Project work might be being done.*

Is this correct?

Comment: Why do you think it might not be correct?

Comment: It's a perfectly valid construction - but interestingly, there's only a single instance of the text [***might be being done***](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22might+be+being+done%22&tbm=bks&sxsrf=ALeKk01ZcR5DvzNdLalB9ahxsAlOw2edLA:1603905221221&source=lnt&tbs=sbd:1&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwif_NrH5NfsAhUPXMAKHcntCQ8QpwUIIw&biw=1448&bih=685&dpr=1.32) in over 20M books indexed by Google. Presumably because it's "clumsy".

Comment: ...even more interestingly, there's also just one single instance of the even more clunky [***ought to be being done***](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22ought+to+be+being+done%22&tbm=bks&sxsrf=ALeKk03I0SGzTI5GXHyO3meYvNV5YQwk7w:1603905451104&source=lnt&tbs=sbd:1&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwim_am15dfsAhXinFwKHaClAG4QpwUIIw&biw=1448&bih=685&dpr=1.32). And that one is in a book called *Elements of English Grammar*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I'm getting four results on might be being done from your link (*The Regulation of Geoengineering*, *Journey: A Novel of America* and a double result for *Using Corpora to Explore Linguistic Variation*). "Ought to be being done" gave me two results: *Elements of English Grammar* and *Kate Caterina*.

Comment: @DonaldHosek: I always ignore any claimed hits in Google Books if I can't see the words ***in context*** (to do that, I always switch from the default "Order by relevance" to "Order by **date**"). Maybe it's irrelevant in this specific case, but I always try to avoid "accidental collocations" where some word sequence I'm searching for turns meaninglessly, spanning the end of one sentence and the beginning of another. Is that what's making the difference for you?

Comment: @FumbleFingers thank you

Comment: _Project work might be being done_ sounds a bit odd. But the _might be being_ passive construction is perfectly ok. Two Google examples: _Worried your child might be being bullied?_ _I think I might be being stalked._

Comment: Instead of using a passive, use an idiom: _Project work may be going on_.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Nope, I can see snippets with the text in the search results. It might be a locale thing since you're apparently in the UK and I'm in the US.

Comment: Writers probably avoid it because it sounds, as FumbleFingers said, clumsy. But I've heard both "might be being done" and "ought to be being done" in ordinary speech in the UK and can't see anything wrong with them *apart* from some clumsiness.

Comment: In passive voice (as taught in India), it is like
He will do it. – It will be done by him.
He will be doing it – It will be done by him. 
Passive voice for both is same.

That way, 
He might do the project work. – Project work might be done by him.
He might be doing the project work. – The project work might be done.

This has always confused me, and I have often wondered why the second of each pair can’t be:
It will be being done by him, and
The project work might be being done.

Comment: @RamPillai: *It will be being done by him* is perfectly valid English, and is indeed the most straightforward "passivisation" of *He will be doing it*, so imho you were effectively mis-taught. It's just that although it's "valid", native speakers would tend to avoid it unless the context very specifically required focus on the *continuous* nature of the activity (at some *specific* future time). It could get worse, with constructions like *It will have been being done by him.* Again, that's perfectly valid - it's just too "clunky" for most contexts.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Yes, as you mentioned, similar is the case in India.  The way it is taught here is that for Perfect Tense and Perfect Continuous Tense, follow the passive voice of Perfect Tense only. As you said, it sounds a little odd while speaking, but technically it should be like 'He has taught English/ English has been taught by him'; He has been teaching English/ English has been being taught by him'.  It is not taught so in India; not sure of other countries where English is a 2nd or 3rd language.